# VBScript Enumerating the Run key

Tags: vbscript, key, registry, enumerate

thank you for this site always full of (deep) knowledge :-)

I'm trying to count the number of Names/values under the Run Key.
I tried this :

```
Const HKCU = 2147483649 ' &H80000001
Set reg = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/default:StdRegProv")
Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
reg.Enumkey HKLM, Key, arrSubKeys
```

If I use another key than "Run" then everything is OK and I can do a for .. in arrSubKeys
But Run always return an empty arrSubKeys
How can I count the number of keys in Run ?

Same with HKLM, HKU, (with the same key).

Also tried with :

```
Set reg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
```

Note : Reading a known key under Run works.

Comment: Run normally has no subkeys.

Comment: Works for me once you a) have a subkey under `Run` in the first place and b) actually use the constant `HKCU` instead of the (undefined) constant `HKLM`. Perhaps a 32/64 bit issue?

Comment: Thank youy for your answer and pointing out the typo in HKCU and HKLM. The script does not have this typo.
But the real point is that I dont want the subkeys but the names/values in that key. So I undertand my code does work and return 0 subkeys but does not return what I want. How can I do this ? (hope it's clear).

Comment: Ok Solution is with
reg.EnumValues

Answer (score 0):

Use :
    reg.EnumValues HKLM, Key, arrValues